# Copy last 15 created files

Tags: batch-file

I have Microsoft Batch files, and in the part of the code I copy from a folder (RootDir) to another (CopyDir) the last created file with a particular naming convention. But now I need to copy the last 15 created files of the same type.
Can you help me please?

```
set lastmod=
pushd %RootDir%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir _UnipolSai_Outlier_Daily_Report_Agg1__UnipolSai_Outlier_Daily_Report_Agg1*.gz /b /o-d /a-d 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a & goto :xx
:xx
if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof
:::
copy /Y "%lastmod%" "%CopyDir%"
```

Comment: First things first, you're asking for `created` so you should be using `dir`'s `/t:c` option, as the last written is the default when using `/o:d` or `/o:-d`.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET /a required=15
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\*" ') DO (
 SET "#0=Y"
 FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,%required%) DO IF DEFINED #0 IF NOT DEFINED #%%b (
  SET "#0="
  SET "#%%b=%%a"
  ECHO process "%%a"
  IF defined #%required% GOTO done
 )
)
SET "#0="
:done
SET #
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

You are obviously familiar with the `dir` options, so I'll leave that issue be.

This approach clears all variables that start with `#`, then uses `#0` as a flag to determine whether he filename has been processed. It's first set to *something* and then #1..#15 are examined.

If #*n* is not defined, then set it to the data line being processed and clear `#0` so only one #*n* will be `set` for each line. I've chosen simply to `echo` the filename found - obviously, this could be any processing you choose.

Once `#15` is set, terminate the loop - with the bonus that each value found is available as `#?`